# Two float numbers ara attached together in my output text file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, output

In my output file two columns corresponding to two float numbers are attached together, forming one column. An example is shown here, is there anyway to separet these two columns from each other?

Here, this is supposed to be 5 columns separated by white-spaces, but space between columns 3&4 is missing. Is there anyway to correct this mistake with some UNIX commands such as cut, awk, sed or even Regular Expressions?

```
3.77388 0.608871 -8216.342.42161 1.88655
4.39243 0.625 -8238.241.49211 0.889258
4.38903 0.608871 -7871.71.52994 0.883976
4.286 0.653226 -8287.322.3195 2.13736
4.29313 0.629032 -7954.651.59168 1.02046
```

The corrected version should look like this:

```
3.77388 0.608871 -8216.34 2.42161 1.88655
4.39243 0.625 -8238.24 1.49211 0.889258
4.38903 0.608871 -7871.7 1.52994 0.883976
4.286 0.653226 -8287.32 2.3195 2.13736
4.29313 0.629032 -7954.65 1.59168 1.02046
```

More info: column 4 is always less than 10, so it only has one digit to the left of decimal point.

I have tried to use awk:

```
tail -n 5 output.dat | awk '{print $3}'
-8216.342.42161
-8238.241.49211
-7871.71.52994
-8287.322.3195
-7954.651.59168
```

Is there any way to separate this column into two columns?

Comment: Not without some prior knowledge of the range of the numbers in columns 3 and 4.

Comment: The range of column 4 is always betweeen zero and 10. so I know that column 4 only has one digit on the left of decimal point!

Comment: Is 10 included in this range ?

Comment: No, not at all! Only one digit   0 to 9

Comment: I think the best answer here would be to fix the program that generates the original output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

```
sed 's/\(\.[0-9]*\)\([0-9]\.\)/\1 \2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+)(\d\.\d+)/$1 $2/' < output.dat > fixed_output.dat
```

Comment: +1. To restrict it to just the 3rd word: `perl -lane '$F[2] =~ s/(\.\d+)(\d\.)/$1 $2/; print "@F"'`

Answer (score 1):

Your input file

```
    $ cat file
    3.77388 0.608871 -8216.342.42161 1.88655
    4.39243 0.625 -8238.241.49211 0.889258
    4.38903 0.608871 -7871.71.52994 0.883976
    4.286 0.653226 -8287.322.3195 2.13736
    4.29313 0.629032 -7954.651.59168 1.02046
```

Awk approach

```
    awk '{
           n = index($3,".")                        # index of dot from field 3              
           x = substr($3,1,n+3) ~/\.$/ ? n+1 : n+2  # Decision for no of char to consider 
          $3 = substr($3,1,x) OFS substr($3,x+1)    # separate out fields
          $0 = $0                                   # Recalculate fields (number of fields NF)
          $1 = $1                                   # recalculate the record, removing excess spacing (the new field separator becomes OFS, default is a single space)
         }1' OFS='\t' file
```

Resulting

```
    3.77388 0.608871    -8216.34    2.42161 1.88655
    4.39243 0.625       -8238.24    1.49211 0.889258
    4.38903 0.608871    -7871.7     1.52994 0.883976
    4.286   0.653226    -8287.32    2.3195  2.13736
    4.29313 0.629032    -7954.65    1.59168 1.02046
```